# System.IO.Stream.Read gets stuck

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, stream

I have an HTTP connection with the server side using System.IO.Stream.Read to read the HTTP request body message.
The problem is that once in a couple of minutes the server gets stuck on the Read statement and doesn't continue until the socket timeout has been reached or the client has closed the connection.

```
int bytesRead = 0;

while (bytesRead < contentLength)
{
  int got = stream.Stream.Read(buffer.Buffer, bytesRead, contentLength - bytesRead);
  bytesRead += got;
}
```

1. It could happen if the stream did not have the amount of data specified by contentLength variable.
   This is not the case because when following the tcp stream with WireShark I see that the whole message body (as specified by contentLength) has reached the server machine.
2. It happens only in the first time that the while loop has been "used", i.e. only in the first time that the stream didn't have "contentLength" number of bytes to read in one try and the while loop had to be re-entered.

Why does it get stuck and does not continue reading data?

Comment: Probably it is the server session time limits.

Comment: any reason you are using System.io.Stream over the HttpWebRequest class? Seems a bit inconvenient?

Comment: @kmcc049 the key word there is "body" - it is pretty common to read/write the body via `Stream`; most commonly, `HttpRequest.InputStream`, or if you are *creating* a request, `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()`.

Comment: @Marc ah ok didn't note the body part, thought he was manually doing the http stuff, something like this `using (var remoteReader = new StreamReader(remoteResponse.GetResponseStream()))
      result = remoteReader.ReadToEnd();` seems far more convenient to read the body....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it had something to do with the fact that I was using the Read method of both the [NetworkStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) (that's the call seen in the code above) and the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8.aspx) that was created by passing the NetworkStream object to it's constructor.

The NetworkStream.Read was used to read the http request message body while the StreamReader.Read was used to read the rest of the request (startline, headers...).
Although the calls happened synchroniously by the same thread, it may have been the cause to the behavior I experienced.

When changing the code to work only with a Socket and perform the reading directly from the socket, it has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the stream is reporting early termination; you should also look at whether `Read` returned a non-positive number, i.e.

```
while (bytesRead < contentLength)
{
  int got = stream.Stream.Read(
       buffer.Buffer, bytesRead, contentLength - bytesRead);
  if(got <= 0) throw new EndOfStreamException(string.Format(
       "Expected {0} bytes; {1} bytes received", contentLength, bytesRead));
  bytesRead += got;
}
```

Basically, if the stream has closed, **every** call to `Read` will return non-positive (probably 0) - so your `while` loop will become a tight cycle of "read 0, add 0, read 0, add 0, read 0, add 0, read 0, add 0".

As a final point, your approach suggests you are allocating a `byte[]` based on the incoming content-length header; just a warning: make sure you sanity-check this and limit it to sane values, otherwise a DOS attack is trivial. Also, *if possible* I would suggest trying to use the streaming API where possible, to *avoid* having to load it all into memory at once (unless you have limited the incoming size such that this isn't a concern).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested what you suggested but the Read statement never returns with zero or smaller number. It always returns with a positive number, up to the point when it just gets blocked at which it never returns.

Comment: @galbarm that *suggests* the request-stream has not been closed by the sender, and has not sent all the data yet; but you say WireShark refutes that... is it compressed (gzip etc) or encrypted in transit?

Comment: No, it is neither compressed or encrypted. A typical content length in my messages is around 5000 bytes, and when the read gets stucked, the bytesRead value is somewhere between 1 to 4999. Yet in wireshark, I see the whole bytes of the message body, exactly as stated by the content length (both in the message in wireshark and in the server variable).

Comment: @galbarm I have no explanation then; I have not seen this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation, your count (contentLength - bytesRead) is wrong. It should be the buffer size.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int count;
while ((count = stream.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{ 
    // do something with the buffer using count as the end marker
    destination.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

If you just want a byte array from the stream, which is more like what you are attempting:

```
byte[] buffer = stream.Stream.ToArray()
```

Or to copy to another buffer:

```
byte[] data = stream.Stream.ToArray();
Array.CopyTo(data , buffer.Buffer, data.Length)
```

Comment: I disagree; the original was more correct; the code in the question was *filling* a sized buffer (not using a scratch-buffer to copy between streams, as shown in your answer). As such, the offset needs to increase each time (such that it is the "bytes already read"), and the "max to read" needs to decrease (such that it is the "bytes not yet read").

Comment: The code is straight out of CopyTo stream implementation in .Net, why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: you are missing my point; the OP ***is not trying to do*** a `CopyTo`. They are filling a buffer with the expected data; that is very different.

Comment: I see what you mean, agree it depends on what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar errors only with clients that didn't flush their streams. MSDN doc on System.IO.Stream.Read says: "The implementation will block until at least one byte of data can be read, in the event that no data is available.". So for some reason there is no data available. I think you could set a certain `ReadTimeout` and stop waiting for more data after a reasonably short time.

A related question has also been posted here: [C# NetworkStream.Read oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193845/c-networkstream-read-oddity). Maybe his solution can also help you.